# RabbitMq error -Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am new to RabbitMq.This is my first Programme .But it is giving some error.
My code is like

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
public class Send {

    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";



    public static void main(String[] argv)
            throws java.io.IOException, TimeoutException {

        ConnectionFactory factory =  new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        Connection connection  =  factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME,false,false,false,null) ;
        String message = null;
        channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
        System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");
        channel.close();
        connection.close();


    }

}
```

and my receiver class is like

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import com.rabbitmq.client.AMQP;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Consumer;
import com.rabbitmq.client.DefaultConsumer;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Envelope;
public class Receive {
    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TimeoutException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
        System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");
        Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
            @Override
            public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
                throws IOException {
              String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
              System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
            }
          };
          channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, consumer);
    }

}
```

Now when I run the class it gives an error like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.FrameHandlerFactory.create(FrameHandlerFactory.java:32)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:676)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:722)
    at Send.main(Send.java:19)
```

I am not getting this error. I have installed the RabbitMq server also. I dont Know how to create the instance of the server . Can anyone help me to solve this error ? do i need to do any changes in eclipse configurations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to specify port address and also please check you can not connect with rabbitMQ with normal http request so please check that as well

Comment: Yeah its working now.. But now it is throwing Null pointer exception ? I dont know why it is throwing exception ?

Comment: i don't know how to implement rabbitMQ in Java because i implemented this from node.js

Comment: I got it....String message = null ; thats why it was throwing exception..Now Its working fine..Thank you ..